# Javascript: "Dangling" Reference to DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom

It seems that in Javascript, if you have a reference to some DOM element, and then modify the DOM by adding additional elements to document.body, your DOM reference becomes invalidated.

Consider the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function work()
{
 var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
 alert(foo == document.getElementById("foo"));

 document.body.innerHTML += "<div>blah blah</div>";
 alert(foo == document.getElementById("foo"));
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "foo" onclick='work()'>Foo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click on the DIV, this alerts "true", and then "false."  So in other words, after modifying `document.body`, the reference to the DIV element is no longer valid.  This behavior is the same on Firefox and MSIE.

Some questions:

Why does this occur?
Is this behavior specified by the ECMAScript standard, or is this a browser-specific issue?

Note: there's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918795/maintain-reference-to-element-after-inserting-into-dom) posted on stackoverflow that seems to be referring to the same issue, but neither the question nor the answers are very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you append to `document.body.innerHTML`, that's equivalent to

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "<div>blah blah</div>";
```

When you assign to `innerHTML` like that the browser has to reparse and therefore recreate that part of the DOM. The div element in `foo` is still *valid*, but it's not a part of the document anymore. Then, of course, when you call `document.getElementById` it gets the new div that replaced `foo`.

The behavior DOM specific, so it's not defined in the ECMAScript standard. It's not defined in any current W3C standard, since `innerHTML` was originally a non-standard property, but it is finally standardized in HTML5.

The solution is to either call `document.getElementById` to get the reference back, or use `document.createElement`, `<element>.appendChild`, etc. instead of setting `innerHTML`.

Comment: `innerHTML` is indeed standardized in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

The reference won't be valid again until the function ends and the DOM refreshes and all the innerHTML is actually converted. Try calling the function again using `setInterval` and you will see the first alert being true again.

Edit: I just noticed that your HTML string doesn't have an id="foo" in it. Put that in it and try again.